# When you remind someone, what is the best verb for what you are doing with the reminder? Provide it? Give it? Supply it? Something else?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I would like to put the following sentence in a report sent to a customer of mine:

"*We would just briefly like to [dispatch] a reminder about [something].*"

I cannot come up with the proper/optimal word for the "[dispatch]" part in this sentence though, so my question is: What is the best word(s) to use in this sentence in place of [dispatch]?

It should be both optimally polite and optimally "correct and normal English".

I can NOT use the word "send", because this sentence covers just one topic out of many in this report (rather than being, say, a dedicated email for the topic in question), so "send" doesn't sound right at all in this context in my opinion.

The following are the closest ones I can think of, but none of them sound quite right to me:

"*We would just briefly like to **give** a reminder about .*"

"*We would just briefly like to **provide** a reminder about .*"

"*We would just briefly like to **supply** a reminder about .*"

What are the other (hopefully better) alternative words?

**Clarification:**
No matter if other complete rephrasings/reformulations of the entire sentence may be more elegant or good (which I'm sure there are a bunch, and I am thankful to the people who have already pointed this out!), the question is still about which verbs that can be best used together with the noun "reminder", to convey that the reminder is being "delivered". The reason for keeping the question specific to this word is that I could not think of, nor google up, any such word, and it got me curious.

Comment: What's wrong with the verb **remind**?

Comment: Also "briefly like" is not right.  It is the reminder that is brief, not the desire to send one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, a "reminder" is a type of message, as is an invitation, a bill or a summons. If you remember this then it will be clear that, in the text of the reminder, you should use **give**. Referring to something you are likely to do in the future, **send** may be better.

To Bill:

- Have you billed him?
- No, I'll give him his bill now.
- I'm here to give you your bill.

To Invite:

- Have you invited him?
- No I'll give him his invitation now.

To Remind:

- Have you reminded him?
- No, I'll give him his reminder now.
- I'll send you a reminder later.
- This note is to remind you that...
- Hi! Just giving you that reminder I promised. Hope all is OK. Best etc.

You can of course also send, supply, provide or do any of the other things you do with messages, if it is appropriate to do so.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm trying to gently remind someone in a business setting, I'd say something along the lines of

> We just wanted to remind you that...

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a rephrasing! I am indeed aware that the sentence can be rephrased in order to avoid this question altogether, but I am still interested in the answer to my specific asked question though, i.e. which word is best in that exact sentence/context.

Comment: That's the thing.. no native speaker would construct such a sentence. I suppose you could say, "We would like to send out a reminder."

Comment: Thanks again! I specifically excluded the word "send" in the text of the question text though (for the reasons stated there), so is there any other word or words that would be most correct in addition to that (in the context described in the question, i.e. as one smaller item in a larger report about many other things too)? PS. I just added a little clarification to the end of the question text too.

Comment: As a native English speaker, I'm not sure I understand your reluctance to use the word "send". :/ The word "remind" is a verb and does not really need another verb as a modifier.